# Change icon in aud_play_pause()

Tags: javascript, html, dom, audio

I have an image that plays and stops the track perfectly. I am trying to alternate the image source from `play.png` to `pause.png` depending on if the track is playing or not.

Here's the code I have that is working to start/stop the audio, only with a static play.png image. How can I change the `src` attribute using javascript between `pause.png` and `play.png`?

```
<img src='play.png' onclick="aud_play_pause()">

<audio id="audio1">
  <source src="audio1.mp3" type="audio/mp3">
</audio>

<script>
var myAudio=document.getElementById("audio1");

function aud_play_pause(){
  if (myAudio.paused){
      myAudio.play();
  } else {
      myAudio.pause();
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to use javascript's DOM manipulation functions to change this like so:

```
var myAudio = document.getElementById("audio1");
var image = document.getElementsByTagName("img")[0];

function aud_play_pause(){
  if (myAudio.paused){
      myAudio.play();
      image.setAttribute("src", "pause.png");
  } else {
      myAudio.pause();
      image.setAttribute("src", "play.png");
  }
}
```

Although it is better to reference the `img` element by its ID, I used its tag name since it was the only one there.